# Search for all shortcuts to a folder in Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I need to place shortcuts to a Google Drive Folder in a number of places. I'm writing some code to first find a list of all the existing shortcuts, identify which ones are missing and then create the missing ones.

I'm stuck on the first step. [Google API docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/shortcuts#search_for_a_shortcut) show how to search for all shortcuts and even for all shortcuts to folders but when I attempt to use the same pattern to find all shortcuts to a specific folder it fails.

Here are my attempts using the Google API Explorer at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list (I'm using Google API Explorer to be language agnostic as I first need to see what the API expects. I'm not asking for help with the coding itself.)

Set `fields` parameter to files `(kind,name,mimeType,shortcutDetails)`

Click Execute. It will show a list of shortcuts.

Set `q` parameter to  `mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut'`

Set `q` parameter to `shortcutDetails.targetMimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'`

Click Execute. It will show a list of all shortcuts to folders.

The shortcutDetails object has a second property `targetId`. It would make sense to be able to filter on that too.

Set `q` parameter to `shortcutDetails.targetId = 'your_google_folder_id'` and click Execute.
The response pane shows 400 - Invalid Value. What am I doing wrong?

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "q"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
}
```

Comment: In the current stage, `shortcutDetails.targetMimeType = '###mimeType###'` can be used as the search query. But, `shortcutDetails.targetId = 'your_google_folder_id'` cannot be used as the search query. Unfortunately, it seems that this is the current specification. So as the current workaround, I think that after the values were retrieved with `shortcutDetails.targetMimeType = '###mimeType###'`, it is required to filter `targetId` by a script. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 1):

As @tanaike mentions, the current state of the API doesn't allow querying shortcuts by targetId. The workaround as proposed could be to filter the response.